# Creating a cointegration matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, correlation

I have a few time series that I can create a correlation matrix easily with the `.corr`, but how can I create a cointegration matrix? Or how do I create any other matrix based on a few time series using another test statistic? 
The `.corr` elegantly creates a matrix for you, but is there another way to do this?